# Displaying div after failed AJAX request (div always hidden)

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a problem displaying a div notification using the following code:

```
$.ajax({    
    url: url,
    cache: false,  
    async: false,
    success: function (data) 
    {
        response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    },
    error: function(){
        showAlert('contentContainer', { type: 'danger', title: 'Error', text: 'Connection Failed' });
    }
});
```

When the server is down the div should show. However the div is always added hidden. Using the `showAlert()` method on other places when no network error occured is working fine.

```
function showAlert(parentDiv, options) {
    $alertDiv = $('<div></div>')
        .show()
        .prop({ id : 'alert'})
        .addClass('alert-' + options.type)
        .append($('<button></button')
            .attr({ type: 'button'})
            .addClass('close')
            .data('dismiss', 'alert')
            .html('X')
            .on('click', function() {
                $(this).parent().remove();
            })
        );

    if("title" in options) {
        $alertDiv.append($('<h4></h4>')
            .html(options.title)
        );
    }

    $alertDiv.append($('<p></p>')
        .html(options.text)
    );

    $('#' + parentDiv).prepend($alertDiv);
}
```

Browser Console:

```
Failed to load resource                     http://192.168.182.130:8080/js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js
  send                                      jquery-3.1.0.min.js:4
  r.extend.ajax                             jquery-3.1.0.min.js:4
  getFromDatabase                           utils.js:251
  (anonymous function)                      (index):39
  r.event.dispatch                          jquery-3.1.0.min.js:3
  q.handle
```

Any ideas whats happening here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `$('#' + parentDiv).prepend($alertDiv);` ... what is `parentDiv` in this context?  Have you tried inspecting the DOM after the failed AJAX call to see if you can find your div somewhere?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the div is being inserted. It's only `style='display: none'` instead of `block`. This only happens after the network error. Inserting the div works fine otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm ... I have found a solution to my problem.

However I don't know why this is happening.

```
$alertDiv = $('<div style="display: block !important"></div>')
```

The code above works for me. Thanks for your help!